# It doesn't show up even though I add Featured Image in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, database, phpmyadmin

About 10 days ago, I changed my hosting company and I asked the hosting company I just switched to to move my site's files to their own servers. And then the transition was made, my website was working.

However, when I wanted to add a new content later, I noticed that even though I uploaded and added the Featured Image, when I published the content, it did not appear in the content. And likewise the Focus Keyword of the Rankmath plugin is not saving either.

As you can see in the image, the area I marked with red should have featured images. But it doesn't save even though I add it.

Well, at this point, is the problem with the database of the site or am I having a different problem?

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/featured-image-not-saving-after-update/ there is information about how the database should be. I changed the values here as they should be and many tables were missing the AUTO_INCREMENT value. However, nothing changed

[image]

---

New notice: They talked to the hosting company and fixed the AUTO_INCREMENT value in wp_options. However, I still cannot add featured images.

Another problem was that the Rankmath plugin was not registering the focus keyword. After I fixed this, I can now save. However, as I said, I can't add featured images yet.

Comment: If you look at the developer tools  console, does it show an error regarding a missing image?  That is where I would start.

Comment: Hi Steve, no it doesn't give any visual-related error on the console.

Comment: The problem is most likely with your WordPress theme. Either you need to activate some setting to display a featured image, or you had some custom code in your previous host that did that. Know that not all themes show the featured image by default.

Comment: There has to be an error on the dev console or the image would show up. What is the img src url? Can you paste it into a browser and open it?